# Convert System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, .net, image

I'm tying together two libraries. One only gives output of type `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource`, the other only accepts input of type `System.Drawing.Image`.

How can this conversion be performed?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
private System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapFromSource(BitmapSource bitmapsource)
{
  System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap;
  using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
    enc.Save(outStream);
    bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
  }
  return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: There is one issue: you will lose the transparency (for a bitmap with alpha channel).

Answer (score 16):

This is an alternate technique that does the same thing.  The accepted answer works, but I ran into problems with images that had alpha channels (even after switching to PngBitmapEncoder).  This technique may also be faster since it just does a raw copy of pixels after converting to compatible pixel format.

```
public Bitmap BitmapFromSource(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource bitmapsource)
{
        //convert image format
        var src = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.FormatConvertedBitmap();
        src.BeginInit();
        src.Source = bitmapsource;
        src.DestinationFormat = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32;
        src.EndInit();

        //copy to bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(src.PixelWidth, src.PixelHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        src.CopyPixels(System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, data.Scan0, data.Height * data.Stride, data.Stride);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

        return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to dispose the `bitmap` object! `using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(...)) { ... }`

Comment: @aholmes why people should worry about the `bitmap` object to be disposed? it is the responsibility of the caller, not the implementer

Comment: I forgot why I wrote that comment. I think I intended to write `using(Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFromSource(...)) {...}`

Comment: very good! can you say when it is required to convert the image format (first part of code)?

Comment: Of all the answers on SO, this is by far the fastest